# using the boost asio server session from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, server, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I have written a threaded server much like this one: [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp)

And a client: [https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/blocking_tcp_client.cpp](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)

They seem to work fine together when the client is talking directly with the server session. But now I would like to create another thread that would use the servers ioservice to send small messages. How would this be possible? I have read that shared_ptr would be one option, but have not got it working...

Inside the session class I define:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<session> session1;
static session1 create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
{
    return session1(new session(io_service));
}
```

Then I define a global session_ptr as

```
session::session1 new_session1 = nullptr;
```

Then in the acceptor I start the session as:

```
new_session1 = session::create(tcp_io_serviceServer);
acceptor_.listen();
acceptor_.async_accept(new_session1->socket(), boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

and in the handle_accept:

```
new_session1->start();
```

Now what I would like to achieve, is that when the async_read of the server session gets a message from client to start a new thread:

```
if (dataReceived[0] == _dataStartCameraThread)
{
    pthread = boost::thread(boost::bind(StartProcess, server));
}
```

then in that thread I want to send messages to the client as:  `new_session1->write1(error)` as

```
void write1(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    boost::asio::async_write(tcpsocket, boost::asio::buffer(sbuf, 1), boost::bind(&session::handle_dummy, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
```

But without the shared_ptr approach I cannot make this work. It claims that the file handle is not valid.

And using the shared_ptr approach I cannot seem to write anything from the server side, I can only read:

> write failed. The file handle supplied is not valid

I checked that the socket is closed even though it just received the message.

Any suggestions where I should go here?

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, you should try to make the code self-contained. It sounds like you should be able to write that in 30-40 lines. Right now I see a lot of claims made that make little sense and no code to show for it (like "And using the shared_ptr approach I cannot seem to write anything from te server side" - I'd love to look at a program that shows that error)

Comment: You may also want to fix your links. Description points to one part of documentation and reference to another. You also mix up different versions of the asio library... quite confusing.

Comment: Without knowing things like what `session::start` does and how the `io_service` is serviced, I'm not sure how we can help.